# Ethernet is connected but there is no internet

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, internet

I'm new to Raspberry Pi and have had an issue which has bugged me for quite some time. I'm running Raspian Jessie on my Model B Computer, and Ethernet seems to be working because all three of the yellow and green lights are on and the two arrows are blue. But when I go onto Chromium and search something it's not available. The same goes for APT commands.

Thanks.

Update: Here are the results of ifconfig and cat /etc/network/interfaces/

```
ifconfig:

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:99:e9:ec  
          inet addr:169.254.208.241  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9ae4:ae1e:7e1d:1888/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:42646 (41.6 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:817 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:817 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:64848 (63.3 KiB)  TX bytes:64848 (63.3 KiB)



cat /etc/network/interfaces:


# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
 wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: What does `ifconfig` show?

Comment: Also, did you update the system time. It would fail because it thought it was 2014 something and because of that all the certificates were deemed invalid.

Comment: during the first start system must have asked you the internet country. Have you selected the right one. Also do try to run sudo apt-get update

Comment: @Milliways I have made a text document with the restults of ifconfig and cat /etc/network/interfaces/ it is stored on my raspberry Pi  but I'll get it soon.

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev Thankyou for the information. Although I think DHCP is working on my router I will sure investigate.

Answer (score 1):

`ifconfig` shows an address starting with 169.254, a link-local address. It gets assigned when there's no DHCP server in your network which tells the RPi (among other things) what network route to take to reach the Internet.

You should connect your RPi to a router which has DHCP enabled, and actually connected to the Internet.

Comment: I think it's /etc/network/interfaces that's the problem. But I'm still confused what's causing problems.

Comment: Your `/etc/network/interfaces` seems fine to me. If your router is working (i.e. when you plug a laptop instead of the RPi, it gets Internet access), then something else on your RPi is misconfigured. Did you change any config files, started/stopped services etc? Alternatively, look into `dhcpcd` logs and see what happens there when you plug the network cable.

Comment: I tried re-installing raspbian and changing dhcpcd.conf but that hasn't worked.

Comment: I've checked my router's page and it says dhcp is enabled.

Comment: Hello sorry for my absence. I've reinstalled raspbian this time without NOOBS yet still my Rapberry Pi fails to connect to the internet or obtain an IP.

Comment: FINALLY some hope has been found! When I plugged my Raspberry Pi into the back of my router and went on to it's site I found it had connected under an IP address. A bit more experimenting and hopefully I might be able to access the Interwebs in desktop like setup.

Answer (score 1):

All along my switch was not properly connected to my router. Thanks for helping everyone!